# What is wrong with my leader board

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4, cocos2d-iphone

My game won't show up on game center and I have been trying to figure this out all day, it has been driving me nuts. I want to save a string with the object key "score" onto the leader boards. I must be missing something very obvious but I have no idea. Sorry to bother you guys but this is just making me mad lol. The bundle id is moocowcurtis and i did put it in info.plist

gamecentermanager.h

```
  #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
  @class GKLeaderboard, GKAchievement, GKPlayer;

  @protocol GameCenterManagerDelegate <NSObject>
  @optional
  - (void) processGameCenterAuth: (NSError*) error;
  - (void) scoreReported: (NSError*) error;
  - (void) reloadScoresComplete: (GKLeaderboard*) leaderBoard error: (NSError*) error;
  - (void) achievementSubmitted: (GKAchievement*) ach error:(NSError*) error;
  - (void) achievementResetResult: (NSError*) error;
  - (void) mappedPlayerIDToPlayer: (GKPlayer*) player error: (NSError*) error;
  @end

 @interface GameCenterManager : NSObject
 {
NSMutableDictionary* earnedAchievementCache;    
id <GameCenterManagerDelegate, NSObject> delegate;
 }

  //This property must be attomic to ensure that the cache is always in a viable state...
 @property (retain) NSMutableDictionary* earnedAchievementCache;

 @property (nonatomic, assign)  id <GameCenterManagerDelegate> delegate;

   + (BOOL) isGameCenterAvailable;

- (void) authenticateLocalUser;

- (void) reportScore: (int64_t) score forCategory: (NSString*) category;
- (void) reloadHighScoresForCategory: (NSString*) category;

- (void) submitAchievement: (NSString*) identifier percentComplete: (double) percentComplete;
- (void) resetAchievements;

- (void) mapPlayerIDtoPlayer: (NSString*) playerID;
@end
```

leaderboard.m file

```
   #import "leaderboard.h"
       #import "GameCenterManager.h"

 @implementation leaderboard

-(id) init
{
   [[GameCenterManager sharedGameCenterObject] reportScore:score forCategory: kLeaderboardID]; 
   int highScore = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"score"] intValue];
   return self;
}

  -(void)displayLeaderboard
  {
    GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardViewController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController       alloc] init];
leaderboardViewController.leaderboardDelegate = self;

AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

[app.navController presentModalViewController:leaderboardViewController animated:YES];
 }



#pragma mark GameKit delegate

  -(void) achievementViewControllerDidFinish:(GKAchievementViewController *)viewController
{
AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[app.navController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

 -(void) leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish:(GKLeaderboardViewController *)viewController
{
AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[app.navController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }

// on "dealloc" you need to release all your retained objects
- (void) dealloc
 {  [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

leaderboard.h

```
   #import "GameCenterManager.h"

   @interface leaderboard: CCLayer<GKLeaderboardViewControllerDelegate>
@end
```

GameCenterManager.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


   @class GKLeaderboard, GKAchievement, GKPlayer;



 @protocol GameCenterManagerDelegate <NSObject>
 @optional
  - (void) processGameCenterAuth: (NSError*) error;
 - (void) scoreReported: (NSError*) error;
  - (void) reloadScoresComplete: (GKLeaderboard*) leaderBoard error: (NSError*) error;
  - (void) achievementSubmitted: (GKAchievement*) ach error:(NSError*) error;
  - (void) achievementResetResult: (NSError*) error;
 - (void) mappedPlayerIDToPlayer: (GKPlayer*) player error: (NSError*) error;
  @end

  @interface GameCenterManager : NSObject
   {
NSMutableDictionary* earnedAchievementCache;
id <GameCenterManagerDelegate, NSObject> delegate;
   }

  //This property must be attomic to ensure that the cache is always in a viable state...
  @property (retain) NSMutableDictionary* earnedAchievementCache;

  @property (nonatomic, assign)  id <GameCenterManagerDelegate> delegate;

 + (BOOL) isGameCenterAvailable;

- (void) authenticateLocalUser;

- (void) reportScore: (score)  forCategory: (NSString*) category;
- (void) reloadHighScoresForCategory: (NSString*) category;

- (void) submitAchievement: (NSString*) identifier percentComplete: (double) percentComplete;
- (void) resetAchievements;

- (void) mapPlayerIDtoPlayer: (NSString*) playerID;
@end
```

AppSpecificValues.h

```
   #define kEasyLeaderboardID @"com.appledts.EasyTapList"
   #define kHardLeaderboardID @"com.appledts.HardTapList"
   #define kAwesomeLeaderboardID @"moocowcurtis"
```

Comment: is it a typo, or you really are trying to send a string as score? score must be an int64_t as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

You say "I want to save a string with the object key "score" onto the leader boards."

But on this line, score must be an int64_t not string :

```
[[GameCenterManager sharedGameCenterObject] reportScore:score forCategory: kLeaderboardID];
```

Comment: ok i replaced the int64_t with gamecentermanager but still not working at all.

Comment: I believe you should stop doing software development right now. You have no idea what you are doing.